# Dynamically populate a choice field and get the non-chosen fields in the post data

Tags: python, django

I have a form where I'm trying to compare two objects (`Cards`) that are randomly selected from the database. In my form, I tried to dynamically populate a choicefield with the two cards, and in the view I'm trying to create an object (`CardComparison(winning_card,losing_card)`) with the choice of the user.

I've overwritten the `__init__` of the form to dynamically populate the card choices, and it's working fine. The problem is that when the user selects a card, it only passes the selected card, and I'm not able to figure out which card is NOT chosen in the view.

I'm new to Django, and I've realized the more I struggle with this, a dynamic choice field may not be what I actually want to use, so a suggestion for a better method would also be greatly appreciated.

forms.py:

```
def get_new_comparison():

    left_card = #get a random card (code hidden for cleanliness)
    right_card = #get a second random card
    left_card_choice = (left_card, left_card.name)
    right_card_choice = (right_card, right_card.name)

    return [left_card_choice, right_card_choice]

class CompareCardsForm(forms.Form):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    post_flag = False
    if kwargs.get('post_flag'):
        post_flag = kwargs.pop('post_flag')

    super(CompareCardsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    if post_flag and len(args) > 0:
        card_name = args[0].get('cards_to_compare')
        card_obj = Card.objects.get(name=card_name)
        card_choice = [(card_obj,card_name)]
        self.fields['cards_to_compare'] = 
             forms.ChoiceField(choices=card_choice, widget=forms.RadioSelect()) 
             #Because everytime the __init__ is called the choices are randomized, I need to set the choices to the POST data's choices otherwise the selected card may not be in the form when it's trying form.is_valid()
    else:
        self.fields['cards_to_compare'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_new_comparison(), widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

views.py:

```
def CompareCards(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CompareCardsForm(request.POST, post_flag=True)
    if form.is_valid():
        print(form.cleaned_data['cards_to_compare'])
        # Here is where I want to create a new comparison using the two cards
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('comparecards'))
    else:
        print(form.errors.as_text())

else:
    form = CompareCardsForm()

return render(
    request,
    'mtg_compare/comparecard.html', 
    {'form': form}
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is actually by using the template file. By adding hidden fields in the template file and by setting the choices to an accessible variable in the form, you can pull the fields and add them to the POST message, so that I'm able to access them in the view.

comparecard.html:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block content %}

<h1>Compare Cards</h1>
<h2>Choose a card to win the matchup</h2>
<p>
<p>

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ form.cards_to_compare }}
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ form.card_list }}" name="var_name_1" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py:

```
class CompareCardsForm(forms.Form):

def get_fresh_comparison():
    return get_new_comparison()

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    post_flag = False
    if kwargs.get('post_flag'):
        post_flag = kwargs.pop('post_flag')

    super(CompareCardsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    if post_flag and len(args) > 0:
        card_name = args[0].get('cards_to_compare')
        card_obj = Card.objects.get(name=card_name)
        card_choice = [(card_obj,card_name)]
        self.card_list = card_choice
        self.fields['cards_to_compare'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=card_choice, widget=forms.RadioSelect())

    else:
        self.card_list = get_new_comparison()
        self.fields['cards_to_compare'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=self.card_list, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

views.py:

```
def CompareCards(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CompareCardsForm(request.POST, post_flag=True)
    if form.is_valid():
        print(request.POST.get('var_name_1'))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('comparecards'))
    else:
        print(form.errors.as_text())
```